# Meaning of "scared the hell out of someone"

Tags: meaning, phrases

The phrase I read on yahoo.com is the following one.

> Tendulkar never scared me, says Akhtar.
>   The Pakistani maverick pacer said it was Adam Gilchrist and Brian Lara who **scared the hell** out of him.

Here, I just want to know the meaning of  "scared the hell out of someone."

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Scared the hell out of someone = Scared someone very much.

Comment: the hell, the devil, the bejasus, the life, the living daylights, the crap, the shit, etc., etc...